# How can I stop printing out the same random text string again?

Tags: php

The following PHP code prints out one of the 6 different "test" strings randomly.

How can I print out a "test" string a second time without displaying the first one again?

```
<?php

$Array[] = 'test1';
$Array[] = 'test2';
$Array[] = 'test3';
$Array[] = "test4";
$Array[] = "test5";
$Array[] = "test6";

$RandomIndex =  rand(0,sizeof($Array)-1); 
echo $Array[$RandomIndex];

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean on the "same page" or over a new reload/request?

Comment: I think the best way would be removing the echoed string from the array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `shuffle` and then remove one (`array_pop`) and echo:

```
$Array[] = 'test1';
$Array[] = 'test2';
$Array[] = 'test3';
$Array[] = "test4";
$Array[] = "test5";
$Array[] = "test6";

shuffle($Array);

echo array_pop($Array);
echo array_pop($Array);
```

If you want to do it across page views, put it in the session:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['Array'] = $Array;

shuffle($_SESSION['Array']);

echo array_pop($_SESSION['Array']);
echo array_pop($_SESSION['Array']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try and share the results

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; ){
  $RandomIndex =  rand(0,sizeof($Partner)-1);
  if(!array_key_exists($RandomIndex , $Array)){
    echo $Array[$RandomIndex];
  } $i++;
}
```